# A Big List Type Question

Tags: support, allowed-questions

A commenter on an answer of mine recently asked me to provide some information an offbeat, but good axiomatization of Euclidian geometry. Having little access to *on-line* Tex typesetting, I am considering asking a question of the sort "What are the various axiomatizations of geometry?" and then promptly responding with Hilbert's, Birkhoff's, Prof. Lee's postulate lists as answers on community wiki. Is this appropriate?

Admittedly, you can find most of this stuff on-line (Birkhoff's postulates, SMSG postulates etc.), but you need to know what you are looking for and be specific. It might be nice to have that all in one place.

Or perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Seems viable (and like a good idea) to me.  I'd suggest flagging the question for moderator attention to be made CW immediately after asking; for the answers you want to post immediately, you can make those CW yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be fine. Certainly it's not a crime to have an answer to your own big-list questions. (It's not even a crime to have an answer to your own ordinary questions, although I am somewhat less fond of this.)